# How to create variable name by combining two different variables

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting values from a CSV file and then storing it in a string, now these strings are data that I pass using sendKeys in Selenium. now the thing is I want to combine those String's variable with the for loop count, so how can I do that?

```
String csvFile = "/home/Miscellaneous/demo.csv";
CSVReader csv_reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
List<String[]> strings = csv_reader.readAll();
for(int dime=2 ;dime<strings.size() ;dime++)
{
//Get data from csv file
    String[] csvCell = strings.get(dime);
    String no_of_new_rows_temp = csvCell[2];
    Integer no_of_new_rows = Integer.valueOf(no_of_new_rows_temp);
    String dim_label_1 = csvCell[3];

    for (int no_of_new_rows_fill = 0; no_of_new_rows_fill <= no_of_new_rows; no_of_new_rows_fill++)
    {
//Add Dimentions
        driver.findElement(By.name("dimension[label]["+no_of_new_rows_fill+"]")).sendKeys("dim_label_" + no_of_new_rows_fill);
    }
}
```

The above code does returns my expectation but that is as a String whereas i require it as a variable.

My Expected output should be in such a way "dim_label_" & "no_of_new_rows_fill" in the sendKeys should create

```
dim_label_1
```

By which I can send CSV file data of dim_label_1 to the field.

Comment: try below solution

Answer (score 1):

To create dynamic variable in java its not possible. But you can utilize java collection here to solve this problem

```
 String csvFile = "/home/Miscellaneous/demo.csv";
 CSVReader csv_reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
 List<String[]> strings = csv_reader.readAll();
 Map<String,String> map = new HashMap()<String,String>;
 for(int dime=2 ;dime<strings.size() ;dime++)
 {
 //Get data from csv file
     String[] csvCell = strings.get(dime);
     String no_of_new_rows_temp = csvCell[2];
     Integer no_of_new_rows = Integer.valueOf(no_of_new_rows_temp);
     //String dim_label_1 = csvCell[3];
    map.put("dim_label"+dime,csvCell[3]);
     for (int no_of_new_rows_fill = 0; no_of_new_rows_fill <= no_of_new_rows; no_of_new_rows_fill++)
     {
 //Add Dimentions
         //driver.findElement(By.name("dimension[label]["+no_of_new_rows_fill+"]")).sendKeys("dim_label_" + no_of_new_rows_fill);
        driver.findElement(By.name("dimension[label]["+no_of_new_rows_fill+"]")).sendKeys(map.get("dim_label_" + no_of_new_rows_fill));
     }
 }
```